# how to i set 'no records found' in UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4

I am parsing xml and placing it in a table view.... However when there are no records the table view is just blank. I tried counting the array where the records are stored in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` but It doesn't run this method when no records show so i cannot insert. Where can i set this...?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Look at the method

```
numberOfRowsInSection:
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you're using an array to populate your tableView, called dataArray

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if ([dataArray count] == 0) return 1;
    return [dataArray count];
}

// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    if ([dataArray count] == 0) {
       cell.textLabel.text = @"No Records Found";
    } else {
        cell.textLabel.text = [dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }


    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the  numberOfRowsInSection u can put this.. it will work.